# Procedural Marble Material

Tags: materials, node-editor, procedural

Greetings dear 3D artists!

According to the tutorial on "**Ryan King Art**" YouTube channel called [*"Procedural Marble Material (Blender Tutorial)"*](https://youtu.be/wTzk9T06gdw) I am trying to create a marble material. The second material, *Dark Marble*, produces a pink texture error. This happens when connected to the *Height* input of the **BUMP** node. When connected to the *Normal* input, everything draws well. What can I do in this situation? Blender version 2.93.

**P.S.** I have already created a lot of materials by YouTube tutorials. I've had a lot of similar errors. Before, I didn’t understand what was happening. Now I see that the combination of the **BUMP** node and the *Normal* input on the **Principled BSDF** node gives a pink error when using the *Height* input on the **BUMP** node. This combination of nodes is very often used by bloggers. And everything works well for them. Maybe I have a weak computer for these operations? Here are the parameters of my PC.

Model: Acer Aspire F 15.

CPU: Intel Core i5-7200U 2.5GHz.

Video: NVIDIA GeForce 940MX with 2GB dedicated VRAM.

Memory: 8GB DDR4.

[image: screenshot of the shader]

[image]

Comment: Here is a link to the file with the material. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=2GQBESgn">](https://blend-exchange.com/b/2GQBESgn/)

Comment: can you share your file with us? Because  that shouldn't happen and I don't think that your HW is the issue, oh you just added your file, going to check it

Comment: Okay it works completely fine on my hardware... It shows as it is supposed to be when you put it into Height input (btw Normal input should give you bad normals because it expects blue/purple normal map, not black and white texture)

Comment: Does this mean that this computer is not suitable for processing procedural materials?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, If I cannot replicate your problem there is no way for me to find out what may be wrong, you definitely have minimal requirement to run Blender which is 1GB GPU and I was able to find benchmarks with your card... I would suggest you to try different versions of Blender (this was 2.93.5?) Try some from 2.8, update your drivers if they are not up to date and try to check if it works in other situations or not

Comment: OK. After installing the new nVidia driver, everything began to work. Thanks for the help. Can you give your answer to close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the nVidia driver resolved this issue.